# Firebase async error : InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Tags: angular, firebase, asynchronous, angularfire2

I am fetching list of categories from firebase using angularfire.
Here is the JSON export of database.

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "bread" : {
      "Name" : "Bread"
    },
    "fruits" : {
      "Name" : "Fruits"
    },
    "seasonings" : {
      "Name" : "Seasonings"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "8ji3HjnPD0es5K5rNj2jHpPWeEk1" : {
      "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
      "isAdmin" : true,
      "name" : "Kartik Dolas"
    }
  },
  "vegetables" : {
    "Name" : "Vegetables"
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
...
    constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }
      getCategories(){
        return this.db.list('/categories')  
      }
```

**component.ts**

```
export class PrductFormComponent implements OnInit {
categories$;

  constructor(categServ:CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categServ.getCategories()
    console.log(this.categories$);
    
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">
        {{ c.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

I am using firebase version 7.24 and angularfire2 version 5.4.2.
I want my output to be dropdown of Bread,Fruits,Seasonings but I am getting an error : `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ |async" value="c.$key">
        {{ c.Name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**service.ts**

```
getCategories(): Observable<any>{
    // add valueChanges() here
    return this.db.list('categories').valueChanges();  
  }
```

If $key is not working for any version, use snapshotchanges instead.
**service.ts**

```
getCategories() {
    return this.db
        .list('/categories', (ref) => ref.orderByChild('name'))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
        map((actions) => {
            return actions.map((action) => ({
                key: action.key,
                val: action.payload.val(),
            }));
        }));

}
```

**component.html**

```
<option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
    {{ c.val.name }}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `FireBase` that well but this error most likely means that you are giving an `object` instead of an `observable` to the `async` pipe.

Change the service to this:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
...
    constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }
      // make getCategories method return an Observable of type any
     // ensure there are no errors and indeed that this.db.list
     // returns an observable
      getCategories(): Observable<any>{
        return this.db.list('/categories');  
      }
```

And quickly looking at the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md), it seems like you need `.valueChanges()`.

```
getCategories(): Observable<any>{
        // add valueChanges() here
        return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges();  
      }
```

!!!! Edit !!!!!!

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
getCategories(): Observable<any> {
  return of([{ id: 1, name: 'Jack' }, { id: 2, name: 'John' }]);
}
```

Change `getCategories` to return a static observable like so and see if the `async` pipe works. If it does, it means with your old implementation (return this.db.list('/categories').valueChanges();), you're not returning and observable but for me I thought the `valueChanges` should be an observable. Even if you go to the link I provided, they show you how to use the `async` pipe with it.

Here is the link again: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Comment: It's not working with console error core.js:6142 `ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: I thought that would fix it but anyway, you need to return an observable for the async pipe and not an object.

Comment: It will be your call, please guide me on code changes throughout the functionality.

Comment: Static implementation is working, what's next? Please elaborate.

Comment: So if the static implementation is working that means you have to get the data from firebase and return an observable. I am not skilled with firebase so I am not sure how to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that your loop is iterating over an object/dictionary instead of an array. If this is the case then don't forget your [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```html
     <option *ngFor="let kvp of categories$ | async | keyvalue" [value]="kvp.key">
        {{ kvp.value.Name }}
      </option>
```